# Write to File from string in android

Tags: android, string, file, file-handling

i trying to make an app that will book a vacant classroom however when i am reading from the file its fine but when i write a get null pointer reference error
its a string that i am trying to store in file here is my code.
when i click on the button of the previous intent to come to this intent app crashes.but if i comment "button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()" this block it works fine.

```
public class result extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
TextView tv1;
TextView tv2;
TextView tv3;
EditText ed1;
public String f;
public static String[] strarray = new String[3];
public String slot;
public int roomno;


String[] mystr = null;
```

int i = 0,j;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    f = intent.getExtras().getString("day");
    slot=intent.getExtras().getString("time");
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setText(f);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);


    InputStream fin = null;
    try {
        fin = openFileInput(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(fin);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);
    int c;
    String str = "";
    String abc = "";
    String def = "";
    String xyz = "";
    int j=0;
    try {
        while((str = br.readLine())!= null)
        {

            String temp[] = str.split(" ");
            if (temp[0].compareTo(slot) == 0) {


                if(temp[1].compareTo("0") == 0) {
                    abc = "1301";
                    tv1.setText(abc);
                }
                if(temp[2].compareTo("0") == 0) {
                    def = "1302";
                    tv2.setText(def);
                }
                if(temp[3].compareTo("0") == 0) {
                    xyz = "1303";
                    tv3.setText(xyz);
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }





   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "file read", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i = 0,j;
            String line;

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

                while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    strarray[i] = line;     //Store each line i file in string array.
                    i++;
                }
                for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
                {
                    if(j==0)            //This i hav taken for 2nd slot (starting from 0)
                    //make it if(j==timeslot/time-1)
                    {
                        String temp = strarray[j];
                        //temp = trim(temp);
                        mystr = temp.split(" ",4);          //Processing that particular line ka string.
                        for(int k=0; k<4; k++)
                            //System.out.println(mystr[k]);
                        mystr[roomno] = "1";                        //Changing from 0 to 1 where classroom = 1301 hence here index=1 in mystr[1] = '1'.
                        //Make it mystr[roomno] = "1";


                        str.append(mystr[0]);
                        str.append(" ");
                        str.append(mystr[1]);
                        str.append(" ");
                        str.append(mystr[2]);           //Creating a new changed string
                        str.append(" ");
                        str.append(mystr[2]);



                        strarray[j] = str.toString();   //Since its a buffer convert it to string.

                    }
                }

                br.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileWriter fileWriter = null;
            try {
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
            BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            for(int m=0; m<3; m++)
            {
                String temp = strarray[m];   //Write back everything to a file.
                try {
                    b.write(temp);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    b.newLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                b.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                b.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }});
    }

}
```

EDITED:logcat

ActivityRecord{bd77102 u0 demo.myapplication/.login t49 f}} is not valid; is your activity running?
04-23 05:57:40.028 1298-1317/? W/WindowManager: view not successfully added to wm, removing view
04-23 05:57:40.028 1298-1317/? W/WindowManager: Exception when adding starting window
                                                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{230ab45 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:424)
                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:350)
                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
                                                    at com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:2359)
                                                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:7840)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
04-23 05:57:40.070 1298-1661/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 2036:com.android.providers.calendar/u0a1 (adj 15): empty for 6000s
04-23 05:57:40.095 2336-2353/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-23 05:57:40.097 4016-4016/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/demo.myapplication-2/lib/x86
04-23 05:57:40.124 2336-2353/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:57:40.124 2336-2353/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3818be0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-23 05:57:40.177 1298-1426/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 3978 uid 10060
04-23 05:57:40.273 1505-2475/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb3fd66e0
04-23 05:57:40.785 4034-4034/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
04-23 05:57:40.786 4034-4034/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
04-23 05:57:40.797 4030-4030/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
04-23 05:57:40.798 4030-4030/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
04-23 05:57:40.805 4034-4034/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
04-23 05:57:40.808 4034-4034/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
04-23 05:57:40.821 4034-4034/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-23 05:57:40.821 4034-4034/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-23 05:57:40.826 4030-4030/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
04-23 05:57:40.828 4030-4030/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
04-23 05:57:40.834 2336-2353/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
04-23 05:57:40.834 2336-2353/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
04-23 05:57:40.845 4034-4034/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
04-23 05:57:40.854 4030-4030/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-23 05:57:40.854 4030-4030/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-23 05:57:40.855 4030-4030/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
04-23 05:57:40.861 4030-4030/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
04-23 05:57:40.866 4034-4034/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
04-23 05:57:40.869 1298-1651/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=demo.myapplication/.login} from uid 0 on display 0
04-23 05:57:40.874 4030-4030/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-23 05:57:40.896 4034-4034/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-23 05:57:40.983 951-1011/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-23 05:57:40.985 4016-4052/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-23 05:57:41.034 4016-4052/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-23 05:57:41.079 4016-4052/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:57:41.079 4016-4052/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabeb6be0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-23 05:57:41.323 1505-1505/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = -1,-1
04-23 05:57:41.323 1505-1505/? E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
04-23 05:57:41.323 1505-1505/? D/RichInputConnection: Will try to retrieve text later.
04-23 05:57:41.324 1505-1505/? I/InputAttributes: InputType.TYPE_NULL is specified
04-23 05:57:41.326 1298-1317/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed demo.myapplication/.login: +437ms
04-23 05:57:41.339 1505-1505/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
04-23 05:57:41.345 2336-2353/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2373050
04-23 05:57:41.392 1505-2475/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:57:41.392 1505-2475/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa217dd20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-23 05:57:47.770 1505-1505/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
04-23 05:57:51.444 1370-1370/? V/DeadZone: consuming errant click: (306.0,0.0)
04-23 05:57:51.877 1370-1370/? V/DeadZone: consuming errant click: (306.0,23.0)
04-23 05:57:53.221 1505-2475/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb3fd66e0
04-23 05:57:56.424 1298-1651/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=demo.myapplication.MainActivity cmp=demo.myapplication/.MainActivity} from uid 10060 on display 0
04-23 05:57:56.495 4016-4052/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:57:56.495 4016-4052/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7315e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-23 05:57:56.682 4016-4052/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:57:56.683 4016-4052/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad731560, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-23 05:58:01.516 1298-1312/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=java.util.List com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getAllStackInfos() from ActivityManagerService.java:8937 waiters=0 for 3.523s
04-23 05:58:01.517 1298-1362/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=java.util.List com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getAllStackInfos() from ActivityManagerService.java:8937 waiters=2 for 2.045s
04-23 05:58:01.517 1298-1298/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=java.util.List com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getAllStackInfos() from ActivityManagerService.java:8937 waiters=1 for 3.085s
04-23 05:58:01.518 1298-1331/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=java.util.List com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getAllStackInfos() from ActivityManagerService.java:8937 waiters=3 for 1.505s
04-23 05:58:01.524 1298-1317/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed demo.myapplication/.MainActivity: +5s57ms
04-23 05:58:01.527 4016-4016/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 282 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 05:58:01.529 1505-1505/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
04-23 05:58:01.618 4016-4052/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabe34a30
04-23 05:58:01.631 4016-4052/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabe32960
04-23 05:58:01.723 1505-2475/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:58:01.723 1505-2475/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2125ee0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-23 05:58:06.926 4016-4052/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:58:06.926 4016-4052/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabeb6fe0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-23 05:58:08.489 4016-4052/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabe328f0
04-23 05:58:08.508 1298-1655/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@49d5167 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@e4d1aa
04-23 05:58:09.326 1298-1310/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=demo.myapplication.result cmp=demo.myapplication/.result (has extras)} from uid 10060 on display 0
04-23 05:58:09.461 4016-4052/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:58:09.461 4016-4052/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf7198c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-23 05:58:11.146 1298-1427/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=java.util.List com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getAllStackInfos() from ActivityManagerService.java:8937 waiters=0 for 669ms
04-23 05:58:11.147 4016-4016/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 106 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 05:58:11.149 1298-1331/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=java.util.List com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getAllStackInfos() from ActivityManagerService.java:8937 waiters=1 for 486ms
04-23 05:58:11.151 1298-1312/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=java.util.List com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getAllStackInfos() from ActivityManagerService.java:8937 waiters=2 for 288ms
04-23 05:58:14.618 1298-1317/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed demo.myapplication/.result: +5s279ms
04-23 05:58:14.630 4016-4016/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 208 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 05:58:14.634 1505-1505/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
04-23 05:58:14.662 4016-4052/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabe35980
04-23 05:58:23.591 1505-2475/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb3fd6670
04-23 05:58:27.181 4016-4016/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: tuesday.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:103)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:66)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at demo.myapplication.result$1.onClick(result.java:120)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
04-23 05:58:27.182 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
04-23 05:58:27.189 4016-4016/? W/System.err:    ... 13 more
04-23 05:58:27.189 4016-4016/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: tuesday.txt: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
04-23 05:58:27.190 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
04-23 05:58:27.190 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:87)
04-23 05:58:27.190 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:72)
04-23 05:58:27.190 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileWriter.(FileWriter.java:80)
04-23 05:58:27.190 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at demo.myapplication.result$1.onClick(result.java:167)
04-23 05:58:27.192 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
04-23 05:58:27.192 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
04-23 05:58:27.192 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-23 05:58:27.195 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-23 05:58:27.195 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-23 05:58:27.195 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
04-23 05:58:27.195 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-23 05:58:27.195 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-23 05:58:27.195 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-23 05:58:27.195 4016-4016/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
04-23 05:58:27.196 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-23 05:58:27.197 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
04-23 05:58:27.197 4016-4016/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
04-23 05:58:27.197 4016-4016/? W/System.err:    ... 13 more
04-23 05:58:27.197 4016-4016/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-23 05:58:27.197 4016-4016/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: demo.myapplication, PID: 4016
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
                                                     at java.io.Writer.(Writer.java:62)
                                                     at java.io.BufferedWriter.(BufferedWriter.java:66)
                                                     at java.io.BufferedWriter.(BufferedWriter.java:54)
                                                     at demo.myapplication.result$1.onClick(result.java:178)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-23 05:58:27.201 1298-1309/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity demo.myapplication/.result
04-23 05:58:27.253 1298-1758/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-23 05:58:27.288 1298-1758/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:58:27.288 1298-1758/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9a87fe00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-23 05:58:27.713 1298-1312/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2733b14 u0 demo.myapplication/.result t50 f}
04-23 05:58:29.032 4016-4016/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4016 SIG: 9
04-23 05:58:29.040 1298-1332/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'ffe8ed8 demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.login (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-23 05:58:29.040 1298-1332/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'ffe8ed8 demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.login (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-23 05:58:29.040 1298-1332/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'ccb419b demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-23 05:58:29.040 1298-1332/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'ccb419b demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-23 05:58:29.040 1298-1332/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '4d2f480 demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.result (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-23 05:58:29.041 1298-1332/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '4d2f480 demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.result (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-23 05:58:29.041 1298-1426/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{ccb419b u0 demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.MainActivity}
04-23 05:58:29.041 1298-1426/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'ccb419b demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.MainActivity (server)'
04-23 05:58:29.043 1298-1651/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 4
04-23 05:58:29.053 1298-1427/? I/ActivityManager: Process demo.myapplication (pid 4016) has died
04-23 05:58:29.054 973-1294/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb4580000) throttle end: throttle time(330)
04-23 05:58:29.056 1298-1656/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{4d2f480 u0 demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.result}
04-23 05:58:29.056 1298-1656/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4d2f480 demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.result (server)'
04-23 05:58:29.057 1298-1651/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{ffe8ed8 u0 demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.login}
04-23 05:58:29.057 1298-1651/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'ffe8ed8 demo.myapplication/demo.myapplication.login (server)'
04-23 05:58:29.065 1298-1758/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa1194660
04-23 05:58:29.064 4068-4068/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-23 05:58:29.065 4068-4068/? I/art: Late-enabling JIT
04-23 05:58:29.069 1298-1758/? D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa17bdd00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa02b0080
04-23 05:58:29.077 4068-4068/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
04-23 05:58:29.083 1298-1427/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 4068:demo.myapplication/u0a60 for activity demo.myapplication/.MainActivity
04-23 05:58:29.106 4068-4068/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/demo.myapplication-2/lib/x86
04-23 05:58:29.173 951-1009/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-23 05:58:29.173 4068-4083/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-23 05:58:29.221 4068-4083/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-23 05:58:29.346 4068-4083/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:58:29.346 4068-4083/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabeb6be0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-23 05:58:29.348 1298-1317/? W/AppOps: Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
04-23 05:58:29.565 1298-1317/? W/WindowAnimator: Failed to dispatch window animation state change.
                                                 android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                     at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.onAnimationStopped(IWindow.java:534)
                                                     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked(WindowAnimator.java:286)
                                                     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked(WindowAnimator.java:678)
                                                     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.-wrap0(WindowAnimator.java)
                                                     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(WindowAnimator.java:123)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:856)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
04-23 05:58:29.729 1298-1317/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed demo.myapplication/.MainActivity: +671ms
04-23 05:58:29.734 1298-2833/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 4016 uid 10060
04-23 05:58:29.742 1505-1505/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
04-23 05:58:29.751 1505-1505/? E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
04-23 05:58:29.751 1505-1505/? D/RichInputConnection: Will try to retrieve text later.
04-23 05:58:29.766 1505-1505/? E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
04-23 05:58:29.766 1505-1505/? W/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor. Setting caps mode without knowing text.
04-23 05:58:29.776 1505-1505/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 1,1
04-23 05:58:29.833 1505-2475/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:58:29.833 1505-2475/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa217d8a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: Always helps to include the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call setContentView() on a Button reference that has never been initialized to non-null.

Try something like

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.whateverYouCalledYourButtonInTheXML);
```

Your subsequent error is:

```
open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system
```

Which tends to indicate that you are trying to write to a file in a disallowed location, perhaps the root directory of the device, if you failed to specify an appropriate location.  You may need to prepend something like the result of `getFilesDir()` called on a valid Context such as your Activity itself.

Comment: thanks that helped now able to go to the "result" activity  but now app crashes when i click on the button of result activity

Comment: "the app crashes" is not an acceptable problem statement here.  Your try/catch setup is not very good though - you have failures handled, and then proceed to try to use the result outside of a try{} even when it has failed.

Comment: Look earlier in the log to see if getting the FileWriter failed, and add some positive logging to your code to see if that worked.

Comment: added the whole log from the first activity to last